# How to know the Type of a Property if it is collection in Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
List<MyClass> MyClassPro
{
   get;set;
}

MyClass obj = new MyClass();

obj.MyClassPro = null;
```

Consider the MyClassPro is null. In situation of Reflection i wont be knowing the Classname or Property Name.

If i try to get the Type of property using GetType like ,

```
      Type t = obj.GetType();
```

It is returning "System.Collections.Generic.list. But my expectation is to get the Type as MyClass.

I also tried the way like

```
        foreach(PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetProperties())
        {
             if(propertyInfo.IsGenericType)
             {
              Type t = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj,null).GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
             }
        }
```

But it is returning error because of the Value of the collection property is null so we cant get the Type.

In this situation how can i get the Type of a collection Property.

Please help me !

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you clarify, it doesn't look like that would compile.

Comment: Its not a complete code. Just assume the situation and please give me the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `propertyInfo.PropertyType` instead of `propertyInfo.GetValue(obj,null).GetType()` which should give you the property type even if the property value is `null`.

So when you have a class like

```
public class Foo {
    public List<string> MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and an instance of `Foo` in `obj`, then

```
var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty"); // or find it in a loop like in your own example
var typeArg = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

will give you the value `System.String` (as a `System.Type` instance) in `typeArg`.

Comment: Yes its returning System.Collections.Generic.List. I need the Type of the Property not Collection.

Comment: You should be able to call `GetGenericArguments().First()` on `propertyInfo.PropertyType` like in your own code sample.

Comment: Yes i called. It returned System.Collections.Generic.List.

Comment: I added an example which should clarify what I meant exactly.

Answer (score 6):

Use `propertyInfo.PropertyType` which has property with name `IsGenericType`, e.g.:

```
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
{
    // code ...
}
```

Comment: I used what you suggested. But i want to get the Type if collection property is null.

Comment: i believe you first create contractor for class.
contractor ()
{ List<MyClassPro>  dd = new List<MyClassPro>(); dd = null; }